# Scroll Images in a scrollview Android

Tags: android, eclipse, imageview, scrollview

Hello I am relatively new to android developing. What I am trying to do is create a scroll view where I can scroll through multiples images vertically how do I do that? I tried searching for it but I cannot seem to find a solution for it? should I add multiple image view in a scroll view is that possible? if so how?
please help.

Answer (score 0):

Use [GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) for that

GridView is a ViewGroup that displays items in a two-dimensional, scrollable grid. The grid items are automatically inserted to the layout using a ListAdapter.

Take and try this [Example](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/)

or

Create the RelativeLayout  inside the ScrollView and add multiple imageview inside the Realtive layout..

Comment: Thank you I'll try this example and update you with where I have come!

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you want to scroll through multiples images vertically then you can use the List View OR Grid view in Android.Both scrolls Vertically.If you want to achieve it through scroll View you can do that by using layout weights to your images or assigning fix height to your images i.e you need to do extra efforts.So better to use List View. You can use the below link for the demo of list view : -

```
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/
```

Comment: Thank you I tried the horizontal scroll view and it seemed to work for me. the problem in vertical scroll view is that it doesn't scroll to the next image it just shows one image. I have no idea why! because the same method works fine for horizontal scroll view!